# How to do haproxy session mapping

Tags: haproxy

I have a scenario where i have two tomcat **servers A and B** behind the haproxy, now one of the app servers  have a new version of the war and the other tomcat has a old version of the war file.So at a point of time we will have only the server A active which has a set of users inside it , after a while we enable the server B now any new request that comes should go only to app server B and the old users should still be at app server B. How should this be done in haproxy , i  have enabled session persistence using appsession . Is there a way that this could be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you could accomplish this by adjusting the server weight within an haproxy backend. You can use the socket cli to set weight at run time. [See the documentation for set weight](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#set%20weight). [The documentation for weight states](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#weight):

> The "weight" parameter is used to adjust the server's weight relative
>   to other servers. All servers will receive a load proportional to
>   their weight relative to the sum of all weights, so the higher the
>   weight, the higher the load. The default weight is 1, and the maximal
>   value is 256. A value of 0 means the server will not participate in
>   load-balancing but will still accept persistent connections. If this
>   parameter is used to distribute the load according to server's
>   capacity, it is recommended to start with values which can both grow
>   and shrink, for instance between 10 and 100 to leave enough room above
>   and below for later adjustments.

I've never tried this before, so you will want to experiment to make sure it has the desired result. Also I believe any weight set via the socket cli is going to reset if you restart haproxy.

Comment: Hi @Kyle Brandt , thanks a lot i set the respective weights to the servers listening on the backend from the haproxy cli and it worked. I had done the same step earlier , but i edited the haproxy config file and reloaded the config as i result i lost the sessions. But with the method you had specified it really works fine. Thanks a lot for your help